# Write two models of the language

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, formal-languages

> Language $\mathcal L$ is defined as follows: $$\mathcal L = \{\{ f\},
>  \{P \}, \{ d\} \}$$ where $f$ is a binary function, $P$ is a binary
>   predicate and $d$ is a constant. Consider this sentence $\phi$:
>   $$(\forall x)(\exists y)((f(x,y),d)\in P)$$ 
>  Write two models
>   $\mathbb M_1, \mathbb M_2$ such that $\mathbb M_1 \models \phi $ and
>   $\mathbb M_2 \models \neg\phi$

I have managed to solve this but I am not sure whether or not my solution is correct - this problem appears to be trivial. 
$$\mathbb M_1 = \{\mathbb N, \{+\}, \{\ge\}, \{0\} \}$$
And so we get $$(\forall x)(\exists y)(x+y \ge 0)$$
Which is of course true. 
Now,
$$\mathbb M_2 = \{\mathbb N, \{+\}, \{\le\}, \{0\} \}$$
And now we get this:
$$(\forall x)(\exists y)(x+y \le 0)$$
Which does not work in natural numbers.

Comment: Perfectly correct.

Comment: You may want to use a notation that distinguishes tuples from sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is fine -- this *is* a pretty trivial exercise (just a test of understanding)!

As a supplementary exercise, now find the *smallest* models (meaning the ones with the smallest domains) which will make that wff true and make it false. Also trivial!

(A pernickety footnote: don't talk about models of a language -- languages have *interpretations*, and a particular interpretation may be a *model for a bunch of one or more sentences* from that language, making them all true together.)